# populate dropdown menu on html page from database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to populate a dropdown menu from database, however when i run the code i get no error but the output shows a part of my code with no proper result.

The code on `index.html` page is

```
<section id="services" class="emerald">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <?php
                                $servername = "localhost";
                                $username = "username";
                                $password = "pwd";
                                $dbname = "db";

                                // Create connection
                                $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                                // Check connection
                                if (!$con) {
                                    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                                }

                                $sql = "SELECT treatment_type FROM treatment_type";
                                $result = $con->query($sql);
                                echo "<label for='treatment_type'>Treatment Type: </label>";
                                echo "<select name='treatment_type' id='treatment_type' class='form-control'>";
                                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                echo "<option value='" . $row['treatment_type'] . "'>" . $row['treatment_type'] . "</option>";
                                }
                                echo "</select>";
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

output that i get along with the box is `query($sql); echo "Treatment Type: "; echo "` and the place where the dropdown menu should get displayed shows `".$row['treatment_type']."`

Comment: Try var_Dump($con-error);

Comment: What my firend Naruto from the Leaf village wanted to say is `var_dump($con->error);`

Comment: @Ares Draguna can u plz tell me the correct way to use it

Comment: You should put your connection script to the database in the top of your code : it will be more readable when you will have to access this connection in another place of your template (You should also read about design patterns and MVC to learn a better structure of your code)

For the rest of your problem, I admit I don't totally get what your current output is.

Are you telling that your PHP code is printed without being processed by your server ?

Comment: "but the output shows a part of my code with no proper result" Is it mean, you see your code? Then you need to replace you .html to .php or set your configuration to parse .html as php.

Comment: @jane, I thing I just did... : var_dump($con->error);

Comment: @lolka_bolka That is the actual answer... I did not noticed that the page is .html :)) good eye.. You should post it so the user can accept it ;)

Comment: Server could be configured to parse html as php, so i want to wait for OP answer to this.

Comment: Judging by the way he's coding, I can be fairy sure that he uses localhost, maybe xampp, and I'm sure that the OP does not know how to configure the server to do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then, as i mentioned in my comment: "but the output shows a part of my code with no proper result" Is it mean, you see your code? Then you need to replace you .html to .php or set your configuration to parse .html as php.

*This is for users whom comes later to this question.*

Answer (score 0):

First you should change the file type to .php

then as kern said you should look in to an MVC frame work, for now what i would do is move the connection to a function in a class

This example is using an ODBC connection but the points are the same just change it to mysqli or look in to using PDO

```
public static function functionName($variableToPassToQuery) {

   //Change this part so you are connecting to your database       

    $conn = odbc_connect('SomeDatabase', '', '');
    if (!$conn) {
        exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
    }

   // Change to the SQL you need

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Somewhere WHERE Something = $VariableToPassToQuery)";

    $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
    if (!$rs) {
        exit("Error in SQL");
    }

   //then once the query has been run we need to get the results and put them in to an array          

    while ($data = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
        $row[] = $data;
    }

   //And then return that array 
    return $row;
}
```

put all that in to a class

Now in the Html file which you should change to a PHP file we can do the drop down box like this

so inside a form you would need to tell it we need a dropdown box

```
    <select name="dropdown">
        <?php
         //then for each of the results in the array we need to an an option
         //call the function from the class like this Classname::Functionname($variable) of course if you
         //don't need to pass a variable then dont
        foreach (Classname::functionName($variableToPassToQuery) as $a) {
            echo '<option value=' . $a["SecondRef"] . '>' . $a["Description"] . ' </option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```